SQL command works fine when run manually (SQL Developer) but gives ORA-00922 in Python's oracledb module
I am working with an Oracle SQL database, and I would like to run the command
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';

It works fine when I run it from the SQL Developer app manually. However, when I run it from Python using the oracledb module, I get this error:
Error running SQL script: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
Help: https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-00922/

Just to be clear, I don't have an issue establishing a connection to Oracle using Python.
Here's my code:
import oracledb
import pandas
import os 
import csv
import logging 
import datetime 
import sys 

STARTER_QUERY = r"ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';"

Config = {}
exec(open("config/info-sql.txt").read(), Config) 
# print(Config)

def get_connection():
    connection = oracledb.connect(user=Config["username"], password=Config["password"], dsn=get_dsn(Config['ip'], Config['port'], Config['service_name']))
    return connection 

def run_sql_script(connection, sql_script):
    try:
        print(f"SQL script: {sql_script}")
        logging.info(f"SQL script: {sql_script}")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_script)
        columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
        return df
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error running SQL script: {e}")
        return None
    
connection = get_connection()
if connection is None:
    sys.exit(0)

run_sql_script(connection, STARTER_QUERY)


Is there an issue with how I format the string? Any help would be appreciated.

Remove the ; at the end of the statement. It is a statement terminator and is used by IDEs to determine when one SQL statement ends and the next starts but it is not actually part of the statement so including it in the statement that you are sending to the database will raise a syntax error. fiddle

Thank you- I tried that and it worked. So you're only supposed to include the semicolon in the IDE? (e.g. if I wanted to run two lines of code in the query I wouldn't include a semicolon?)

No, Oracle databases forbid you from running multiple statements in a single command so if you try to send multiple statements then you will get a syntax error. Either send SQL statements one-by-one or else wrap them in a PL/SQL block so that you are sending a single PL/SQL statement (and that can contain multiple nested SQL or PL/SQL statements).

The error is the ; at the end of the SQL statement. ; is a statement terminator used by IDEs to determine when one statement finishes and the next starts and is not part of the SQL statement.
If you try to send a statement to an Oracle database that contains the statement terminator then it will raise a syntax error. Delete the ; and your code will work.
fiddle

If you want to send SQL multiple statements then either:

Send them one-by-one (omitting the statement terminator each time); or
Wrap then in a PL/SQL block as that can contain multiple nested statements. The PL/SQL block must contain the ; terminators for the PL/SQL and SQL statements within it but must not contain the / terminator for the PL/SQL block.



The prefix r at the beginning is redundant since you are not using any escape characters.

Where are you defining get_dsn?

The command ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD' could not retrieve any results, check that first.

Try adding a Try-Except statement to check, something like this:
try:
         print(f"SQL script: {sql_script}")
         logging.info(f"SQL script: {sql_script}")
         cursor = connection.cursor()
         cursor.execute(sql_script)

         if cursor.description:
             columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
             data = cursor.fetchall()
             df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
             return df
         else:
             #Whatever you need
except Exception as e:




The r-string was one of the potential troubleshoots, but that didn't work.

As for get_dsn I took it out of the program so that it would be easier for people to analyze here (but rest assured it is working)

Most of these points do not answer the question asked and should have been left as comments on the question of the OP to clarify rather than as an answer.
